# Applying the decision tree in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, decision-tree

**Description:**

I have a case in finding a solution to a problem. rules to find the solution as follows:

> Case 1: `IF T01 AND T02 AND T03 THEN S01`
>
> Case 2: `IF T04 THEN S02`
>
> Case 3: `IF T04 AND T05 AND T06 THEN S03`

To display the questions on the matter, set based on a decision tree. at the time of problem 1 (T1) asked, then there is a yes or no answer. if you have problems, a selected 'yes'. if it does not have this problem, then selected the answer 'no'. followed by asking about the next problem until a solution (S) is found.

**My question:**

1. how do I apply the rule or the decision tree in a database?
2. whether there are other ways to find a solution (S) but the question
   of problem must be a sequence based on the decision tree?

please see the decision tree on the following link [here](http://oi59.tinypic.com/24cw9ye.jpg).

**Caption:**

```
T = trouble/problem; 
S = solution; 
Y = if answer is YES; 
N = if answer is NO;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved with something like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| decisionId | ifTrueDecisionId | ifFalseDecisionId | 
=====================================================
| T01        | T02              | T04               |
-----------------------------------------------------
| T02        | T03              | S0                |
-----------------------------------------------------
| T03        | S1               | S0                |
-----------------------------------------------------
| T04        | T05              | S0                |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

And so on....

You can then do a SQL query based on the Trouble/Problem stated. The result gives you directions for a new question. Where again you query for the next step.

Comment: I have tried to like it and it works well. But, how about if there are new problems and new solutions? Whether to delete all of record in the table and placing it with a new decision tree?

Comment: Depending how much your tree will change, you can adjust the table entries. If you update an `ifTrueDecisionId` to a different `decisionId` you already create a different branch. You might also consider adding a `TreeId` column. In that you can relate all decisions to a specific tree. So if you have multiple or a new one.. You don't loose references to the old

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ...,
  IF(T01,
    IF(T02,
      IF(T03,
        S01,
        S0
      ),
      S0
    ),
    IF(T04,
      IF(T05,
        IF(T06,
           S03,
           S0,
        ),
        S02
      ),
      S0
    )
  ) AS some_field_alias
...
```

according to http://oi59.tinypic.com/24cw9ye.jpg

using this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

You can use this logic right in mysql query. Each T* could be a sub-request as well as S*.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'll try. However, I would agree with mvbrakel's answer.